# rails how to find with no associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations

I know that this will be an easy one but I'm having real issues working it out.

I have users that can have_many results. I'm trying to work out how to return users that don't yet have any results to the @starters object(from the controller).

```
@users = @event.entires

@starters = @users.where("results = ?", 0)
```

could anyone explain how i would check if a user has no results?

Comment: is `results` an attribute for users?

Comment: To keep it only SQL-away: `@starters = @users.includes(:results).where(results: { id: nil })` this will work with any kind of DataBase

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Best solution (as MrYoshiji commented)

```
@starters = @users.includes(:results).where(results: { id: nil })
```

This will execute the same query as the one in my second solution.

## Other SQL solution

You could use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This way, you will always have all the results from the "left" table (`users`) but you will also have matching records for the "right" table (`results`) eventhough there are non, which will leave you with empty fields that you can check.

```
@starters = @users.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN results ON results.user_id = users.id").where("results.user_id IS NULL")
```

In your case, replace `users` with the name of your "user" model.

## Other Ruby solution

```
@starters = @users.select { |u| !!u.results }
```

Here `!!` will force conversion to a boolean, if there are no `results`, `u.results` will return `[]` (empty array). And `!![]` equals `true`.

Comment: Brilliant - that works a treat. I went with the first solution but i'm having fun playing around with all of them!

Answer (score 0):

Try left joining and finding which one is null

```
@users.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON user.id = result.user_id").where("result.id IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `@users` is an Array, try:

```
@starters = @users.select { |u| u.results.empty? }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get all of the users that do not have any results:

```
@starters = ActiveRecord::Base.execute("select * from users where id not in (select user_id from results)")
```

Another way to do this would be the following:

```
User.where("id not in ?", "(select user_id from results)")
```